# ObjectDetection inference with a SavedModel on TFRecords

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to perform inference using a [SavedModel from the detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/57e075203f8fba8d85e6b74f17f63d0a07da233a/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). I was able to get a working example using the [Object Detection Tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/57e075203f8fba8d85e6b74f17f63d0a07da233a/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). However, it runs far to slowly and I suspect it could be quicker if I use tfrecords as inputs. Additionally, unfortunately I'm stuck using Tensorflow 1.14.

```py
    feature_description = {'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value='')}
    def _parse_function(example_proto):
        # Parse the input `tf.Example` proto using the dictionary above.
        return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)

    sm_dir = '/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_2018_01_28/saved_model'
    sm = tf.saved_model.load_v2(sm_dir)
    f = sm.signatures['serving_default']
    tfr_loc = 'inputs.tfr'
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfr_loc)
    parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_function)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for tfr_i in parsed_dataset:
            imgs_raw = tf.decode_raw(tfr_i['image_raw'], tf.float32)
            imgs_raw = tf.reshape(imgs_raw, [-1, 1028, 768, 3])
            inference = f(imgs_raw)
            sess.run(inference)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Resource AnonymousIterator/AnonymousIterator0/N10tensorflow4data16IteratorResourceE does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this came up for me recently, and I found that most of the answers surrounding this issue were unhelpful. I figured I would post what worked for me to potentially help any future troubleshooters.

Via the TF GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33258

A dev suggested passing `experimental_run_tf_function=False` to `model.compile()`, and this solved my issue. The output looks odd, but the code runs and my model trains successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Eager Execution at the beginning of your script.

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Reference: [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#**iter**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#__iter__)